# Django aggregation and filtering

Tags: django, django-queryset, aggregation

I am working with a model having a date, a group, and an identifier.
I want to retrieve for each group the id of the minimum date value.

My model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Group')
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The goal is to retrieve this:

```
[
    (u'group1', datetime.date(2016, 1, 23), 15 <- Id of the minimum date for group1),
    (u'group2', datetime.date(2015, 6, 25), 314 <- Id of the minimum date for group2),
    ...
]
```

I tried the following:

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('group').annotate(Min('date')).order_by('group')
```

This works fine but gives me only the date:

```
[
    (u'group1', datetime.date(2016, 1, 23)), 
    (u'group2', datetime.date(2015, 6, 25)), 
    (u'group3', datetime.date(2015, 6, 26))
    ...
]
```

I cannot find a way to add the id to those tuples without breaking the grouping clause in SQL.
I tried to do a where date = min(date), but aggregation is forbidden in where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Subquery()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expressions in Django 1.11.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

oldest = MyModel.objects.filter(group=OuterRef('group')).order_by('date', 'id')
qs = (
    MyModel.objects
    .values_list('group')
    .annotate(
        Min('date'),
        Subquery(oldest.values('id')[:1]),
    )
    .order_by('group')
)
```

The field `'id'` is added to `.order_by('date', 'id')` in order to get the oldest item, in the case that more items exist on the same day in the same group. It is not necessary if the date is unique.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I checked the documentation and it seems to be exactly what I need.
I am currently using Django==1.8.18, is there any equivalent of this ?

Comment: If the `date` field is the current date then you can use `.annotate(Min('date'), Min('id'))` otherwise you must add a piece of SQL, e.g. by [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method. You can export it by `str(qs.query)` in Django 1.11 and paste the SQL of field that has subquery to "extra". The example for SubQuery is similar to your question. That means that no simple solution existed before.

Comment: Thank you again for this answer, it solved my issue !